# Loggedin user and other users variables getting mixed in Pug template

Tags: node.js, express

I have a basic express app, where I have a pug layout, and then other pug templates that extend layout.

**My problem is:**

When on the homepage, on the main nav, I can see the photo of the loggedin user, which is `CORRECT`

But then when I go to see the profile of another user, I see the photo on the main navbar, as if they where logged in, `INCORRECT`

**On my layout.pug I have this:**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= `${title} | ${h.siteName}`

  body
    block header
      header.top
        nav.nav
            if user
              li.nav__item: a.nav__link.ph4(href="/logout", class=(currentPath.startsWith('/logout') ? 'nav__link--active' : ''))
                span Logout
              li.nav__item: a.nav__link.ph4(href="/account", class=(currentPath.startsWith('/account') ? 'nav__link--active' : ''))
                img.avatar.pa2(src=`/uploads/${user.photo}`)
            else
              li.nav__item: a.nav__link(href="/register", class=(currentPath.startsWith('/register') ? 'nav__link--active' : '')) Register
              li.nav__item: a.nav__link(href="/login", class=(currentPath.startsWith('/login') ? 'nav__link--active' : '')) Log In

    .content
      block content
        p This is the default!

    block scripts
```

**Then I have a controller that sends some user based on its slug:**

```
exports.getUserBySlug = async (req, res, next) => {

  const user = await User.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug })
  let embed = {}
  if (!user) return next();


  res.render('user', {
    user,
    title: user.name,
    embed: embed.html,
  });
};
```

And also a configuration on my app that always provides me the loggedin user and I can use it in pug as `user`

```
// pass variables to our templates + all requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.h = helpers;
  res.locals.flashes = req.flash();
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.currentPath = req.path;
  next();
});
```

**Question:** How can I do it, so that the on the navbar I always show the loggedin user?

Comment: Post your route/middleware order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change this line:

```
res.locals.user = req.user || null;
```

to:

```
res.locals.loggedinUser = req.user || null;
```

and use loggedinUser on my template